# Why does selfdestruct() have an address requirement?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, selfdestruct

Why must selfdestruct take the contract's original `msg.sender` argument? Isn't the idea that it 'self' destructs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes an address as an argument(not necessarily the contract deployer's) to send the remaining ether in the contract to that address on self-destruction.